# how to connect bluetooth device (forehead thermometer) in React

Tags: reactjs, bluetooth

I want to connect a forehead thermometer in my react project. My forehead thermometer is FORA IR42. The problem is I can't find this device in my chrome. No matter which filters I set(service name or UUID), I only can find my iphone and macbook in chrome's bluetooth device list. The same thing happened when setting acceptAllDevices true. But I can use BLE scanner app to catch the device. Is it possible to get forehead thermometer data through bluetooth? or only manufacturer can reach this goal?[image]

Comment: https://web.dev/bluetooth/ maybe check this out?

Comment: @Gandzal yes, this is the article which I read before. This is weird because there is only apple device can been found in chrome BLE device list.